# Angularjs boolean

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two requirements, From the Json object I need to display Male for M and Female for F and Yes for bool 1 and No for bool 0 in ng-repeat (AngularJS) like

```
<tr ng-repeat ="object in objects"> 

<td> {{object.Gender}}</td> 
<td> {{object.bool}}
```

New to Angular. 
Thanks

Comment: `<td> {{object.Gender === 'M' ? 'Male' : 'Female'}}</td> 
<td> {{object.bool ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}` or Better do it in the model that is being bound itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve that. I'm not going to talk about performance or anything since you're still new to Angular. You'll get there.

Anyway, the simplest I think is to create a controller:

```
angular.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.getGender = function(gender) {
        return gender === 'M' ? 'Male' : 'Female';
    };
});
```

Then:

```
<td> {{ getGender(object.Gender) }}</td>
```